# Decimals in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've been trying to code a section in my cash-register class. Im trying to make it so that it keeps track of the total price as an integer. so for example 18.66 would be 1866. But i still want it to be considered as 18.66 if that makes sense. this is so that it avoids the accumulation of roundoff errors. But i dont want to change the public interface of the class.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

class CashRegister :
    def __init__(self):
        self._itemCount = 0
        self._totalPrice = 0.0

    def addItem(self, price):
        self._itemCount = self._itemCount + 1
        self._totalPrice = self._totalPrice + price

    def getTotal(self):
        return self._totalPrice

    def getCount(self) :
        return self._itemCount

    def clear(self) :
        self._itemCount = 0
        self._totalPrice = 0.0
```

wouldn't i simply change the 0.0's to 0's? or would i go along the way of doing a split method and concatenate them back together?

Comment: Have you considered using [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)?

Comment: Right link for python3 decimal is: http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the data as is.

You can achieve what you want by mean of formatting. If i were you i will add a new function like this:

```
def getTotalAsString(self):
        return "%d" % (self._totalPrice * 100)
```

This approach will give you more flexibility in the future

Comment: It's not always `* 100`, you know? :)